# Use of "static" CSS position

Tags: html, css

I just came across on the [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) that if the position property is not specified, the browser defaults itself to `position: static;`

So if that's the case, what's the purpose of specifying the position property as static explicitly? Is there any specific purpose? If yes, please guide me.

P.S. I'm a beginner in CSS

Comment: This is an odd question. Most, if not all, properties have a default value. You can set an element to the default value if you need to override a value that's been set else where - even though you should try to minimise those cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify it explicitly if you wanted to override a rule that was specified earlier that targets that specific selector. For example, let's say someone does this in a different part of the stylesheet or a different stylesheet altogether:

```
header * {
  position: relative;
}
```

Well, maybe `position: relative` isn't behaving the way you want it to on a specific element, so then you override it:

```
header > .my-special-element {
  position: static;
}
```

That's just one example, but I think that it would be one of the most common scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason you would ever set an element to `position: static` is to forcefully-remove some positioning that got applied to an element outside of your control. This is fairly rare, as positioning doesn't cascade.

Answer (score 0):

The same reason as there is to specify any other property as its default value: To override some other piece of CSS.